# How to compare counts of two different columns for multiple rows and find only mismatches

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables:

```
Table A
--------- 
id | num_of_records
---|---------------
10 | 2
20 | 9
30 | 1
40 | 3

Table B
---------
id | details
---| --------
10 | somedetail 2
10 | somedetail 3
20 | foobar
30 | random
40 | random 2
```

In the above I want to get recods only where the `num_of_recods` from `TableA` do not match the `count(*)` from `TableB` so the result based on above would be:

```
id | difference
---| --------
20 | 8
40 | 2
```

My real `TableB` has around 20M records and `TableA` has around 4k records.

I've written something like this which doesn't work `select id from tableA join on tableB where tableA.num_of_records <> (select count(*) from tableB where id = id);`

Comment: How is 9 - 1 = 9?

Comment: Sorry that was mistake on my part. I have fixe dit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `full join`:

```
select id, coalesce(a.num_of_records, 0) - coalesce(b.cnt, 0)
from a full join
     (select id, count(*) as cnt
      from b
      group by id
     ) b
     using (id)
where a.num_of_records is distinct from b.cnt;
```

This uses `full join` to handle the case when either table is missing an `id`.

Comment: `cnt` is not a column of table b. I actually need to do a `count` on all the records in tableb

Comment: @Anthony . . . `cnt` is defined in the subquery.

Comment: What if the `id` column was not numbers but rather a string and we wanted to do an `upper` on both since there can be mismatches.  would I just do an upper in the `group by`?

Comment: @Anthony . . . Then you would use `on upper(a.id) = upper(bid)` and fix the `select`.